# Can we enroll a user into Banno so they can access plugins/external apps without an account # on core?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are implementing several different plugins, we have some users that may use a financial product that isn't on the core (referral relationship), can we enroll those users into Banno without an account number on core?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to unpack in your question, so please bear with us.

> We are implementing several different plugins

Excellent! We're always excited when folks build with our developer platform.

By the way, we have resources to help you [Prepare Your Press Release](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/launching-your-project/prepare-your-press-release/) and [Share on Social Media](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/launching-your-project/share-on-social-media/) when your plugin is complete and ready to share with the world.

> we have some users that may use a financial product that isn't on the core (referral relationship)

That's 100% fine. There isn't any requirement to tie a plugin's content to any account *on the core*.

It's *common* to have plugins which interact with accounts on the core in a more direct manner (e.g. via [jXchange](https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/) or [SymXchange](https://jackhenry.dev/symxchange-api-docs/symxchange-api/symxchange-interface/)) or in a more indirect manner (e.g. via Banno's [Consumer API](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/getting-started/)), but there is no *requirement* to do so. You can use your own APIs or use APIs from other companies to build your plugins (e.g. as we demonstrate in our [Build a Plugin with External API](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/tutorials/externalapiplugin/) tutorial).

As an example, we've seen developers in the community build plugins which are based on credit scores, digital assets/cryptocurrency, marketing, and more. None of those are directly based on financial products which are *on the core*, and they fit nicely into the Banno user experience as plugins.

> can we enroll those users into Banno without an account number on core?

There's a couple of different ways to interpret that question.

The first interpretation is around *enrollment* into Banno *itself*. Enrolling a new user into Banno *itself* is not part of the Digital Toolkit.

The second interpretation is around enrolling users *into your plugin* (e.g. the financial product behind your plugin). As mentioned earlier, there isn't a requirement to tie a plugin to a financial product that is *on the core*. A very common way to reduce friction for users when they enroll into your plugin is to make use of our [Authentication Framework](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/getting-started/) to get authenticated information about the *user* (which exists in Banno). In particular, the **Authentication Framework** has the concept of an **Identity Token** which provides info about the user that is useful to prefill forms so the user doesn't have to retype information that the institution already knows about the user(see [Tokens](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/) for more info on the Identity Token).

Comment: Thanks Jaime, my question related to enrolling a user in Banno itself. The Banno support team at JHA directed me to the Digital Toolkit team for possible workaround or solutions.